# Zurb Foundation dropdown menu add delay

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, zurb-foundation

I have implemented the Foundation top menu/dropdowns for a client as mega menus. We would now like the dropdown mega menus to be delayed about a half second before it pops up on hover so that users just moving their mouse over the menu to get to another area of the page won't have to maneuver around the megas.

Zurb doesn't support adding a delay at this point so I've been trying to add this to the default foundation.dropdown.js. I'm wondering if this is even possible?

Here is the full js:

```
    ;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

Foundation.libs.dropdown = {
name : 'dropdown',

version : '5.2.2',

settings : {
  active_class: 'open',
  align: 'bottom',
  is_hover: false,
  opened: function(){},
  closed: function(){}
},

init : function (scope, method, options) {
  Foundation.inherit(this, 'throttle');

  this.bindings(method, options);
},

events : function (scope) {
  var self = this,
      S = self.S;

  S(this.scope)
    .off('.dropdown')
    .on('click.fndtn.dropdown', '[' + this.attr_name() + ']', function (e) {
      var settings = S(this).data(self.attr_name(true) + '-init') || self.settings;
      if (!settings.is_hover || Modernizr.touch) {
        e.preventDefault();
        self.toggle($(this));
      }
    })
    .on('mouseenter.fndtn.dropdown', '[' + this.attr_name() + '], [' + this.attr_name() + '-content]', function (e) {
      var $this = S(this);
      clearTimeout(self.timeout);

      if ($this.data(self.data_attr())) {
        var dropdown = S('#' + $this.data(self.data_attr())),
            target = $this;
      } else {
        var dropdown = $this;
            target = S("[" + self.attr_name() + "='" + dropdown.attr('id') + "']");
      }

      var settings = target.data(self.attr_name(true) + '-init') || self.settings;

      if(S(e.target).data(self.data_attr()) && settings.is_hover) {
        self.closeall.call(self);
      }

      if (settings.is_hover) self.open.apply(self, [dropdown, target]);
    })
    .on('mouseleave.fndtn.dropdown', '[' + this.attr_name() + '], [' + this.attr_name() + '-content]', function (e) {
      var $this = S(this);
      self.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if ($this.data(self.data_attr())) {
          var settings = $this.data(self.data_attr(true) + '-init') || self.settings;
          if (settings.is_hover) self.close.call(self, S('#' + $this.data(self.data_attr())));
        } else {
          var target = S('[' + self.attr_name() + '="' + S(this).attr('id') + '"]'),
              settings = target.data(self.attr_name(true) + '-init') || self.settings;
          if (settings.is_hover) self.close.call(self, $this);
        }
      }.bind(this), 150);
    })
    .on('click.fndtn.dropdown', function (e) {
      var parent = S(e.target).closest('[' + self.attr_name() + '-content]');

      if (S(e.target).data(self.data_attr()) || S(e.target).parent().data(self.data_attr())) {
        return;
      }
      if (!(S(e.target).data('revealId')) && 
        (parent.length > 0 && (S(e.target).is('[' + self.attr_name() + '-content]') || 
          $.contains(parent.first()[0], e.target)))) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
      }

      self.close.call(self, S('[' + self.attr_name() + '-content]'));
    })
    .on('opened.fndtn.dropdown', '[' + self.attr_name() + '-content]', function () {
        self.settings.opened.call(this);
    })
    .on('closed.fndtn.dropdown', '[' + self.attr_name() + '-content]', function () {
        self.settings.closed.call(this);
    });

  S(window)
    .off('.dropdown')
    .on('resize.fndtn.dropdown', self.throttle(function () {
      self.resize.call(self);
    }, 50));

  this.resize();
},

close: function (dropdown) {
  var self = this;
  dropdown.each(function () {
    if (self.S(this).hasClass(self.settings.active_class)) {
      self.S(this)
        .css(Foundation.rtl ? 'right':'left', '-99999px')
        .removeClass(self.settings.active_class)
        .prev('[' + self.attr_name() + ']')
        .removeClass(self.settings.active_class);

      self.S(this).trigger('closed', [dropdown]);
    }
  });
},

closeall: function() {
  var self = this;
  $.each(self.S('[' + this.attr_name() + '-content]'), function() {
    self.close.call(self, self.S(this))
  });
},

open: function (dropdown, target) {
    this
      .css(dropdown
        .addClass(this.settings.active_class), target);
    dropdown.prev('[' + this.attr_name() + ']').addClass(this.settings.active_class);
    dropdown.trigger('opened', [dropdown, target]);
},

data_attr: function () {
  if (this.namespace.length > 0) {
    return this.namespace + '-' + this.name;
  }

  return this.name;
},

toggle : function (target) {
  var dropdown = this.S('#' + target.data(this.data_attr()));
  if (dropdown.length === 0) {
    // No dropdown found, not continuing
    return;
  }

  this.close.call(this, this.S('[' + this.attr_name() + '-content]').not(dropdown));

  if (dropdown.hasClass(this.settings.active_class)) {
    this.close.call(this, dropdown);
  } else {
    this.close.call(this, this.S('[' + this.attr_name() + '-content]'))
    this.open.call(this, dropdown, target);
  }
},

resize : function () {
  var dropdown = this.S('[' + this.attr_name() + '-content].open'),
      target = this.S("[" + this.attr_name() + "='" + dropdown.attr('id') + "']");

  if (dropdown.length && target.length) {
    this.css(dropdown, target);
  }
},

css : function (dropdown, target) {
  this.clear_idx();

  if (this.small()) {
    var p = this.dirs.bottom.call(dropdown, target);

    dropdown.attr('style', '').removeClass('drop-left drop-right drop-top').css({
      position : 'absolute',
      width: '95%',
      'max-width': 'none',
      top: p.top
    });

    dropdown.css(Foundation.rtl ? 'right':'left', '2.5%');
  } else {
    var settings = target.data(this.attr_name(true) + '-init') || this.settings;

    this.style(dropdown, target, settings);
  }

  return dropdown;
},

style : function (dropdown, target, settings) {
  var css = $.extend({position: 'absolute'}, 
    this.dirs[settings.align].call(dropdown, target, settings));

  dropdown.attr('style', '').css(css);
},

// return CSS property object
// `this` is the dropdown
dirs : {
  // Calculate target offset
  _base : function (t) {
    var o_p = this.offsetParent(),
        o = o_p.offset(),
        p = t.offset();

    p.top -= o.top;
    p.left -= o.left;

    return p;
  },
  top: function (t, s) {
    var self = Foundation.libs.dropdown,
        p = self.dirs._base.call(this, t),
        pip_offset_base = (t.outerWidth() / 2) - 8;

    this.addClass('drop-top');

    if (t.outerWidth() < this.outerWidth() || self.small()) {
      self.adjust_pip(pip_offset_base, p);
    }

    if (Foundation.rtl) {
      return {left: p.left - this.outerWidth() + t.outerWidth(), 
        top: p.top - this.outerHeight()};
    }

    return {left: p.left, top: p.top - this.outerHeight()};
  },
  bottom: function (t, s) {
    var self = Foundation.libs.dropdown,
        p = self.dirs._base.call(this, t),
        pip_offset_base = (t.outerWidth() / 2) - 8;

    if (t.outerWidth() < this.outerWidth() || self.small()) {
      self.adjust_pip(pip_offset_base, p);
    }

    if (self.rtl) {
      return {left: p.left - this.outerWidth() + t.outerWidth(), top: p.top + t.outerHeight()};
    }

    return {left: p.left, top: p.top + t.outerHeight()};
  },
  left: function (t, s) {
    var p = Foundation.libs.dropdown.dirs._base.call(this, t);

    this.addClass('drop-left');

    return {left: p.left - this.outerWidth(), top: p.top};
  },
  right: function (t, s) {
    var p = Foundation.libs.dropdown.dirs._base.call(this, t);

    this.addClass('drop-right');

    return {left: p.left + t.outerWidth(), top: p.top};
  }
},

// Insert rule to style psuedo elements
adjust_pip : function (pip_offset_base, p) {
  var sheet = Foundation.stylesheet;

  if (this.small()) {
    pip_offset_base += p.left - 8;
  }

  this.rule_idx = sheet.cssRules.length;

  var sel_before = '.f-dropdown.open:before',
      sel_after  = '.f-dropdown.open:after',
      css_before = 'left: ' + pip_offset_base + 'px;',
      css_after  = 'left: ' + (pip_offset_base - 1) + 'px;';

  if (sheet.insertRule) {
    sheet.insertRule([sel_before, '{', css_before, '}'].join(' '), this.rule_idx);
    sheet.insertRule([sel_after, '{', css_after, '}'].join(' '), this.rule_idx + 1);
  } else {
    sheet.addRule(sel_before, css_before, this.rule_idx);
    sheet.addRule(sel_after, css_after, this.rule_idx + 1);
  }
},

// Remove old dropdown rule index
clear_idx : function () {
  var sheet = Foundation.stylesheet;

  if (this.rule_idx) {
    sheet.deleteRule(this.rule_idx);
    sheet.deleteRule(this.rule_idx);
    delete this.rule_idx;
  }
},

small : function () {
  return matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries.small).matches &&
    !matchMedia(Foundation.media_queries.medium).matches;
},

off: function () {
  this.S(this.scope).off('.fndtn.dropdown');
  this.S('html, body').off('.fndtn.dropdown');
  this.S(window).off('.fndtn.dropdown');
  this.S('[data-dropdown-content]').off('.fndtn.dropdown');
},

reflow : function () {}
};
    }(jQuery, this, this.document));
```

Here is a test I had some success with as far as a delay, but the dropdown still appeared after mouseleave:

```
    .on('mouseenter.fndtn.dropdown', '[' + this.attr_name() + '], [' + this.attr_name() + '-content]', function (e) {
      var $this = S(this);
      var t = setTimeout(function() {
      if ($this.data(self.data_attr())) {
        var dropdown = S('#' + $this.data(self.data_attr())),
            target = $this;
      } else {
        var dropdown = $this;
            target = S("[" + self.attr_name() + "='" + dropdown.attr('id') + "']");
      }

      var settings = target.data(self.attr_name(true) + '-init') || self.settings;

      if(S(e.target).data(self.data_attr()) && settings.is_hover) {
        self.closeall.call(self);
      }

      if (settings.is_hover) self.open.apply(self, [dropdown, target]);
    }, 500);
$(this).data('timeout', t);
    })
    .on('mouseleave.fndtn.dropdown', '[' + this.attr_name() + '], [' + this.attr_name() + '-content]', function (e) {
      var $this = S(this);
      self.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if ($this.data(self.data_attr())) {
          var settings = $this.data(self.data_attr(true) + '-init') || self.settings;
          if (settings.is_hover) self.close.call(self, S('#' + $this.data(self.data_attr())));
        } else {
          var target = S('[' + self.attr_name() + '="' + S(this).attr('id') + '"]'),
              settings = target.data(self.attr_name(true) + '-init') || self.settings;
          if (settings.is_hover) self.close.call(self, $this);
        }
      }.bind(this), 150);
    })
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: How did you solve this?